# Trust anchor for certification path not found on old android devices

Tags: java, android, ssl, websocket

I'm use the com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client lib to connect in a websocket server, on new Android devices with Android version > 6.0 the connection is ready.

But, on connect with Android version < 6.0 i'm get this error:

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

This lib not have an method to insert a SSL certific, then, i need a easy solution and to know because this error happens only android versions < 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the library to support custom a custom `SSLSocketFactory`.

Or, find some replacement library that does support a custom `SSLSocketFactory`.

Or, switch the server to another SSL certificate, one from a more historically-relevant certificate authority.